# How to decrease the number of queries with get_posts and ACF?

Tags: advanced-custom-fields, get-posts, performance

In my index.php file, inside the classic WordPress loop, I had to query posts in order to retrieve the ones with a relationship value created with a custom field (managed with ACF plugin).

I managed to do it using the get_posts() function and a foreach loop. But, as I have 300 posts, it slows down the page load time.

So, in this perspective, I was looking for a way to reduce the amount of posts fetched by get_posts(), or the number of queries, using different parameters. But, it seems the parameters I'm using are increasing the number of queries.

This is the code I'm trying to improve :

```
    <?php
    $artists = get_posts(array(
      'post_type'           => 'post',
      'numberposts'         => '1',
      'meta_query'          => array(
            array(
              'key'       => 'relation', // name of custom field
                'value'   => '"' . get_the_ID() . '"', // matches exactly "123", not just 123. This prevents a match for "1234"
                'compare' => 'LIKE'
            )
      )
    ));

    ?>
    <?php if( $artists ) : ?>
      <?php foreach( $artists as $artist ) : ?>
        <p>
          <a href="<?php echo get_permalink( $artist->ID ); ?>"><?php echo get_the_title( $artist->ID ); ?></a>
        </p>
      <?php endforeach; ?>
    <?php endif; ?>
```

First of all, I'm using the paramater `'numberposts' => '1'`, instead of the default `'numberposts' => '5'`, in order to limit the number of posts and the query time, but i dont see any improvement, and if i use 'numberposts' => '-1' (which is not limiting the number of posts), the number of queries decrease and the load time as well. Why ?

Then, if i use this chunk of code instead of the previous one, the number of queries increase but the load time decrease :

```
<?php
    // trying to limit the number of posts targeting only the one with a specific relationship field
    $ids = get_field('relationship_field_name', false, false);

    $artists = get_posts(array(
      'post_type'           => 'post',
      'numberposts'         => '1',
      'post__in'            => $ids,
      )
    ));

    ?>
<?php if( $artists ) : ?>
  <?php foreach( $artists as $artist ) : ?>
    <p>
      <a href="<?php echo get_permalink( $artist->ID ); ?>"><?php echo get_the_title( $artist->ID ); ?></a>
    </p>
  <?php endforeach; ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

**EDIT :**

The most efficient piece of code I've been able to produce is, with (according to Query Monitor plugin) only **616 queries and 0,4775s Database Query Time** :

```
<?php
$ids = get_field('relation', false, false);

$artists = get_posts(array(
  'post_type'     => 'post',
  'numberposts'   => '-1',
  'post__in'      => $ids,
));

?>
<?php if( $artists ) : ?>
  <?php foreach( $artists as $artist ) : ?>
    <p>
      <a href="<?php echo get_permalink( $artist->ID ); ?>"><?php echo get_the_title( $artist->ID ); ?></a>
    </p>
  <?php endforeach; ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

If I set the parameter 'numberposts' to 1, or if I let to its default value, I obtain **1069 Queries and 0,7291s Database Query Time**.

What a Im missing with get_posts() ? How to optimize the efficiency of the code, decrease the number of queries and the load time ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's everything OK with `get_posts()` since it creates the single `WP_Query` instance per call. You can check the query by creating that instance:

```
<?php
$test_query = new WP_Query(
    array(
        'post_type'      => 'post',
        'posts_per_page' => -1, // any number, does not matter
        'post__in'       => $ids, // should be an array!
    )
);

echo $test_query->request;
```

Adding `'meta_query'` or other parameters will (not necessarily) increase query complexity (and, therefore, query time), but will not increase the number of queries.

It's not enough information to find out *why* there are so many queries.

**Adopted since OP's comment** (later on):

See. Load time depends on the number of queries (first) and their complexity (second) (or, otherwise, or, both). I can't figure out why do you have so many queries when I don't see what happens inside your Loop, inside `while`. I think you do the same query inside the Loop for each of 300 posts. Don't do `get_posts()` inside the Loop. If you need some relations between posts, use taxonomies,  they were designed for this purpose. Like `tags` or `categories` or custom `movies`, `nappers`, `wooden toys`, `bicycles`, `etc`. Do you see belonging on to another? Querieng custop fields was one of the most resource-eating things in WordPress. Use Taxonomies where queries are adopted to frequent use. Rethink the architecture excluding that plugin and come up with a new idea.

Comment: If I understand, the number of queries isn't necessarily the cause of the load time, but the complexity of the query sometimes (especially when there is a meta_query). I've checked the query, but I'm still not advanced enough to understand how to improve it from a performance perspective. I assume if I reduce the number of posts affected by the query with more precise parameters, the load time will decrease. I could for example create a CPT, move the posts in this CPT and then filter them with the post_type parameter. This could reduce the query time.

Comment: Thanks a lot. The only thing I can't figure out is how to create relationship between 150 posts "books" to 150 posts "author" using taxonomies, except creating a tag for each author. But I will dig into this. Using get_posts() inside the loop is definitively not a got idea :) ! Thanks again.

Comment: Register a number of taxonomies, as you say 'books' and 'author', and go with them. Forget about `get_posts()` but ask `WP_Query` to return only posts where 'books' and 'author' belong to.

Comment: Thanks to your comments, I feel I'm on the right way coding it. Thanks a lot !